# Azure Login Using Service Principal is failing with 401 - Invalid client secret provided

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have created a new application registration in my Azure Portal like so:

```
Home -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New Registration -> myApp.
```

I also created 3 different secrets for the app.  Now I'm trying to log in via command line using one of those secrets like this:

```
az login --service-principal -u <Application (client) ID> -p <secret> --tenant <Directory (tenant) ID>
```

I'm getting the following error message:  (key parts of the error only)

```
Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided."error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2021-06-01 20:59:28Z","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}
```

The Application (client) ID and Tenant ID values were taken from the "Overview" section of the Application registration.

Please check out the screenshot below.

[image]

If you can tell me where I've gone astray ... I'd appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Made a new app registration, this worked for me: `az login --service-principal -u client-id-here -p "client-secret-here" --tenant tenant-id-here`.

Comment: @juunas did you use the "value" of the secret key that's shown when you first create the secret?  or the encrypted value?  Just for kicks I tried the "Value" and now I get the error "No Subscriptions found for <App client id>"

Comment: Yeah you need to use the value it gives you. The error you then get happens because the app does not have access to any Azure resources. You can work around that with `--allow-no-subscriptions` if you need to do e.g. Azure AD management with Az CLI.

Comment: @juunas if you want to create an answer, I'll pick it and close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a new app registration, this worked for me: `az login --service-principal -u client-id-here -p "client-secret-here" --tenant tenant-id-here`.

When you create a client secret, you need to use the Value it gives you. You might then get an error because the app does not have access to any Azure resources. You can work around that with `--allow-no-subscriptions` if you need to do e.g. Azure AD management with Az CLI.